# How to convert a ANSI project into a UNICODE one?

Tags: c++

I have a ANSI C++ project developed by Visual Age. I want to convert it into Unicode so it can
display multi-lingual characters correctly in an English operation system. I changed all the `char` variables into `wchar_t` after defining the `UNICODE` macro.

Is this the right way to do it? There are some APIs in the source code only accept `char*` strings (such as `system()`, `fopen()`, `mkdir()` ). How can I make them work with `wchar_t` strings since all of the strings in the code are changed into `wchar_t`?

Comment: Lasciate ogne speranza, voi ch'intrate

Comment: fast solution. you cat overload function with wchar_t and in this function call original one

Comment: there are Unicode equivalents APIs for your ANSI functions or you can just use winapi methods http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library to handle your unicode characters.

Comment: How many lines of code are we talking about here, ballpark? A thousand? hundred-thousand? a few million? Just assessing the pain level.

Comment: @ouou There are _no_ Unicode equivalents in standard C or C++.  There is some support for `wchar_t`, but `wchar_t` is not necessarily Unicode, and when it is, it may be either UTF-16 (Windows and AIX) or UTF-32 (most other systems, inluding Linux).

Comment: @JamesKanze I meant the unicode version of some APIS eg: `wmkdir()`, `wfopen()`, `wsystem()` ... maybe this can help http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/c-unicode.html

Comment: @ouou: Note that the cheat sheet is clearly labeled "Microsoft C/C++ Source Code"  It's non standard and not portable

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of representing unicode character strings, the most common are:

- encoded in `UTF-8`, stored in `char` strings
- encoded in `UTF-16`, stored in strings composed of 16 bit integers
- encoded in `UTF-32`, stored in strings composed of 32 bit integers.

For UTF-16 and UTF-32 you have to be aware of the byte order of your system, and decide if you want to communicate your strings in big or little endian order.

There is an older encoding named `UCS-2`, with this encoding you can only represent unicode characters below 0x10000. You should not use this, not all chinese characters can be represented in it.

Another thing to be aware of is that `wchar_t` is either 2 bytes or 4 bytes wide, so on some systems it can be used to hold `UTF-16`, and on others `UTF-32` characters.

Another thing to be aware of: most string length functions will return the number of bytes or words counted, not the number of unicode symbols represented.

I personally prefer to store everything internally and externally as `UTF-8`, and convert to 16 or 32 bit encoding as needed. That way avoiding byte order issues.

Chances are that if you make sure everything is encoded in `UTF-8`, most stuff will just work.

Comment: For UTF-16 and UTF-32, the internal byte order is irrelevant; integer types just work.  For external communication, you'll want to convert them to or from UTF-8 anyway.

Comment: With regards to using UTF-8 internally: most stuff won't work, because most stuff assumes single byte encodings.  For example, there are no equivalents to the functions in `<ctype.h>` for UTF-8. Or for UTF-16, for that matter, and not all platforms support UTF-32, and even for those that do, the equivalent functions don't work right in all cases.  (Things like `toupper` still work at a code point level, which means that the cannot be correct.)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without knowing what you're doing with the
text, and where it comes from.  If all you're doing is reading
it from a file and displaying it, then just changing `char` to
`wchar_t` might be enough.  (But in this case, you might want to
consider sticking with `char`, and using UTF-8.)  Once you start
doing more, the issues become more complicated:

- As you've observed, things like file names will generally have
  to be `char`.  Using UTF-8 works around this problem, sort of,
  but what character strings are or are not legal is still an open
  issue, and largely system dependent.
- Parsing may become more difficult, depending on what you're
  trying to do.  You'll probably have to forgo the simple functions
  in `<ctype.h>`; C++ has functions in `<locale>` which you can
  use with `wchar_t`, but they're a lot less easy to use.  And
  while `isspace` or searching a specific delimiter work more or
  less as advertised, things like `toupper` become extremely
  problematic (since there's not universally a one to one
  relationship between upper and lower).
- When reading and writing files in UTF-16 or UTF-32, endianness
  becomes an issue.  Regardless of the type and encoding used
  internally, I'd stick with `char` and UTF-8 anytime I import or
  export data.

On the whole, I'd tend to stick with `char`, and UTF-8, unless
I was doing significant parsing or text manipulation.  In which
case, I'd look into the ICU library, which provides very
complete support for UTF-16.  And unless I was 100% sure that
I would only have to support a single platform, forever, I would
avoid `wchar_t`, which has no real standard size or encoding;
ICU, for example, puts their UTF-16 characters in an `unsigned
short`.  (The same could be said for `char`, but machines where
`char` isn't 8 bits are extremely rare, and for
internationalization, about the only encoding you're likely to
encounter *is* UTF-8.)